# Raytune is throwing error: "module 'pickle' has no attribute 'PickleBuffer'" when attempting hyperparameter search

Tags: python, pickle, huggingface-transformers, ray-tune

I am more or less following [this example](http://4/1AY0e-g4pMh6JPfkexh5nvWf9lvug3sHK98_jxAnwhsYlrB3F20Jkp350PKY) to integrate the ray tune hyperparameter library with the huggingface transformers library using my own dataset.

Here is my script:

```
import ray
from ray import tune
from ray.tune import CLIReporter
from ray.tune.examples.pbt_transformers.utils import download_data, \
    build_compute_metrics_fn
from ray.tune.schedulers import PopulationBasedTraining
from transformers import glue_tasks_num_labels, AutoConfig, \
    AutoModelForSequenceClassification, AutoTokenizer, Trainer, TrainingArguments

def get_model():
    # tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name, additional_special_tokens = ['[CHARACTER]'])
    model = ElectraForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained('google/electra-small-discriminator', num_labels=2)
    model.resize_token_embeddings(len(tokenizer))
    return model

from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, precision_recall_fscore_support
def compute_metrics(pred):
    labels = pred.label_ids
    preds = pred.predictions.argmax(-1)
    precision, recall, f1, _ = precision_recall_fscore_support(labels, preds, average='weighted')
    acc = accuracy_score(labels, preds)
    return {
        'accuracy': acc,
        'f1': f1,
        'precision': precision,
        'recall': recall
    }

training_args = TrainingArguments(
    "electra_hp_tune",
    report_to = "wandb",
    learning_rate=2e-5,  # config
    do_train=True,
    do_eval=True,
    evaluation_strategy="epoch",
    load_best_model_at_end=True,
    num_train_epochs=2,  # config
    per_device_train_batch_size=16,  # config
    per_device_eval_batch_size=16,  # config
    warmup_steps=0,
    weight_decay=0.1,  # config
    logging_dir="./logs",
)

trainer = Trainer(
    model_init=get_model,
    args=training_args,
    train_dataset=chunked_encoded_dataset['train'],
    eval_dataset=chunked_encoded_dataset['validation'],
    compute_metrics=compute_metrics
)

tune_config = {
    "per_device_train_batch_size": 32,
    "per_device_eval_batch_size": 32,
    "num_train_epochs": tune.choice([2, 3, 4, 5])
}

scheduler = PopulationBasedTraining(
    time_attr="training_iteration",
    metric="eval_acc",
    mode="max",
    perturbation_interval=1,
    hyperparam_mutations={
        "weight_decay": tune.uniform(0.0, 0.3),
        "learning_rate": tune.uniform(1e-5, 2.5e-5),
        "per_device_train_batch_size": [16, 32, 64],
    })

reporter = CLIReporter(
    parameter_columns={
        "weight_decay": "w_decay",
        "learning_rate": "lr",
        "per_device_train_batch_size": "train_bs/gpu",
        "num_train_epochs": "num_epochs"
    },
    metric_columns=[
        "eval_f1", "eval_loss", "epoch", "training_iteration"
    ])

from ray.tune.integration.wandb import WandbLogger
trainer.hyperparameter_search(
    hp_space=lambda _: tune_config,
    backend="ray",
    n_trials=10,
    scheduler=scheduler,
    keep_checkpoints_num=1,
    checkpoint_score_attr="training_iteration",
    progress_reporter=reporter,
    name="tune_transformer_gr")
```

The last function call (to trainer.hyperparameter_search) is when the error is raised. The error message is:

> AttributeError: module 'pickle' has no attribute 'PickleBuffer'

And here is the full stack trace:

> ---
>
> AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call
> last)
>
> in ()
> 8     checkpoint_score_attr="training_iteration",
> 9     progress_reporter=reporter,
> ---> 10     name="tune_transformer_gr")
>
> 14 frames
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/transformers/trainer.py in
> hyperparameter_search(self, hp_space, compute_objective, n_trials,
> direction, backend, hp_name, **kwargs)    1666     1667
> run_hp_search = run_hp_search_optuna if backend ==
> HPSearchBackend.OPTUNA else run_hp_search_ray
> -> 1668         best_run = run_hp_search(self, n_trials, direction, **kwargs)    1669     1670         self.hp_search_backend = None
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/transformers/integrations.py in
> run_hp_search_ray(trainer, n_trials, direction, **kwargs)
> 231
> 232     analysis = ray.tune.run(
> --> 233         ray.tune.with_parameters(_objective, local_trainer=trainer),
> 234         config=trainer.hp_space(None),
> 235         num_samples=n_trials,
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ray/tune/utils/trainable.py in
> with_parameters(trainable, **kwargs)
> 294     prefix = f"{str(trainable)}_"
> 295     for k, v in kwargs.items():
> --> 296         parameter_registry.put(prefix + k, v)
> 297
> 298     trainable_name = getattr(trainable, "**name**", "tune_with_parameters")
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ray/tune/registry.py in
> put(self, k, v)
> 160         self.to_flush[k] = v
> 161         if ray.is_initialized():
> --> 162             self.flush()
> 163
> 164     def get(self, k):
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ray/tune/registry.py in
> flush(self)
> 169     def flush(self):
> 170         for k, v in self.to_flush.items():
> --> 171             self.references[k] = ray.put(v)
> 172         self.to_flush.clear()
> 173
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ray/_private/client_mode_hook.py
> in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
> 45         if client_mode_should_convert():
> 46             return getattr(ray, func.**name**)(*args, **kwargs)
> ---> 47         return func(*args, **kwargs)
> 48
> 49     return wrapper
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ray/worker.py in put(value)
> 1512     with profiling.profile("ray.put"):    1513         try:
> -> 1514             object_ref = worker.put_object(value)    1515         except ObjectStoreFullError:    1516             logger.info(
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ray/worker.py in
> put_object(self, value, object_ref)
> 259                                         "inserting with an ObjectRef")
> 260
> --> 261         serialized_value = self.get_serialization_context().serialize(value)
> 262         # This *must* be the first place that we construct this python
> 263         # ObjectRef because an entry with 0 local references is created when
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ray/serialization.py in
> serialize(self, value)
> 322             return RawSerializedObject(value)
> 323         else:
> --> 324             return self._serialize_to_msgpack(value)
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ray/serialization.py in
> _serialize_to_msgpack(self, value)
> 302             metadata = ray_constants.OBJECT_METADATA_TYPE_PYTHON
> 303             pickle5_serialized_object = 
> --> 304                 self._serialize_to_pickle5(metadata, python_objects)
> 305         else:
> 306             pickle5_serialized_object = None
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ray/serialization.py in
> _serialize_to_pickle5(self, metadata, value)
> 262         except Exception as e:
> 263             self.get_and_clear_contained_object_refs()
> --> 264             raise e
> 265         finally:
> 266             self.set_out_of_band_serialization()
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ray/serialization.py in
> _serialize_to_pickle5(self, metadata, value)
> 259             self.set_in_band_serialization()
> 260             inband = pickle.dumps(
> --> 261                 value, protocol=5, buffer_callback=writer.buffer_callback)
> 262         except Exception as e:
> 263             self.get_and_clear_contained_object_refs()
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ray/cloudpickle/cloudpickle_fast.py
> in dumps(obj, protocol, buffer_callback)
> 71                 file, protocol=protocol, buffer_callback=buffer_callback
> 72             )
> ---> 73             cp.dump(obj)
> 74             return file.getvalue()
> 75
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ray/cloudpickle/cloudpickle_fast.py
> in dump(self, obj)
> 578     def dump(self, obj):
> 579         try:
> --> 580             return Pickler.dump(self, obj)
> 581         except RuntimeError as e:
> 582             if "recursion" in e.args[0]:
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pyarrow/io.pxi in
> pyarrow.lib.Buffer.**reduce_ex**()
>
> AttributeError: module 'pickle' has no attribute 'PickleBuffer'

My environment set-up:

- Am using Google Colab
- Platform: Linux-5.4.109+-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-18.04-bionic
- Python version: 3.7.10
- Transformers version: 4.6.1
- ray version: 1.3.0

What I have tried:

- Updating pickle
- Installed and imported pickle5 as pickle
- Made sure that I did not have a python file with the name of 'pickle' in my immediate directory

Where is this bug coming from and how can I resolve it?

Comment: From https://discuss.ray.io/t/cant-pickle-pyarrow-dataset-expression/1685/11, it looks like a fix hasn't been made yet...

Comment: It seems like it has something to do with the order of the imports. If I have the time I'll try to pinpoint exactly what ordering causes the issue

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error when trying to use pickle.dump(), for me it worked to downgrade pickle5 from version 0.0.11 to 0.0.10

Comment: Could you expand on this? What is pickle5? I cannot find it in my pip freeze list..=

Comment: [pickle5](https://pypi.org/project/pickle5/) is a version of pickle that has newer features of pickle and is compatible with older versions of Python. I got the same error when using pickle alone.

Answer (score 2):

I also encountered this error on Google Colab trying ray tune hyperparameter search with the huggingface transformers.

This helped me:

```
!pip install pickle5
```

Then

```
import pickle5 as pickle
```

After the first run there will be the pickle warning to restart the notebook and the same error. After the second “Restart and run all” the ray tune hyperparameter search begins.

Answer (score 0):

Not a "real" solution but at least a workaround. For me this issue was occurring on Python 3.7. Switching to Python 3.8 solved the issue.